# Erro ao consumir WebService SOAP em php

Tags: php, web-service, soap, wsdl

Estou tendo uma dificuldade em conseguir consumir um WebService em PHP, sempre que faço a requisição via SoapClient eu obtenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unmarshall'

A chamada esta sendo feita da seguinte maneira:

```
$conta = 'conta';
$token = 'token';
$url = 'url/soap?WSDL';

$soap_client = new SoapClient($url);

$soap_client->ProcessoAndamentosTodos($token, $conta, $parametro3);
```

Alguém saberia como resolver? Ou o que eu estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Tem algum modelo de como o WS deveria responder?

Comment: @DanielCosta, na verdade ele deveria retornar uma lista com as informações. Uma coisa que eu percebi mas confesso que não sei o que é: parece que este WSDL tem um protType que seria por onde eu conseguiria acessar os métodos, sem acessar eles diretamente. Só que não sei como fazer isso usando o SoapClient do php. Fiz um teste com C# e lá, eu consegui acessar, mas utilizando o tal do protType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, eu consegui resolver o problema, irei deixar a solução do que eu fiz aqui, caso alguém esteja com este mesmo problema. O WSDL em questão usa o porType, e por isso ele não deixa passar os parâmetros diretamente igual eu havia feito. Desta forma, eu consegui acessar os métodos da seguinte maneira:

```
$conta = 'conta';
$token = 'token';
$url = 'url/soap?WSDL';

$soap_client = new SoapClient($url);

$params = array('param1'=>$param1, 'param2'=>$param2, 'param3'=>$param1);

var_dump($soap_client->ProcessoAndamentosTodos($params));
```

Outra forma de acesso que também funciona é a seguinte:

```
var_dump($soap_client->__soapCall('ProcessoAndamentosTodos', array($params)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro quer dizer que algum metodo/atributo esta retornando `Null` e voce esta tentando acessar o atributo `NodeValue` dele. Tenta verificar os nulos das respostas do WS.